# List Last record of each item in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

Each item(item is produced by Serial) in my table has many record and I need to get last record of each item so I run below code:

```
SELECT ID,Calendar,Serial,MAX(ID) 
FROM store 
GROUP BY Serial DESC
```

it means it must show a record for each item which in that record all data of columns be for last record related to each item but the result is like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------+
  ID    |            Calendar        |  Serial |    MAX(ID)  |
-------------------------------------------------------------|
7031053 |   2016-05-14 14:05:14 79.5 |  N10088 |    7031056  |
7053346 |   2016-05-14 15:17:28 79.8 |  N10078 |    7053346  |
7051349 |   2016-05-14 15:21:29 86.1 |  J20368 |    7051349  |
7059144 |   2016-05-14 15:50:27 89.6 |  J20367 |    7059144  |
7045551 |   2016-05-14 15:15:15 89.2 |  J20366 |    7045551  |
7056243 |   2016-05-14 15:25:34 85.2 |  J20358 |    7056245  |
7042652 |   2016-05-14 15:18:33 83.9 |  J20160 |    7042652  |
7039753 |   2016-05-14 11:48:16 87   |  J20158 |    7039753  |
7036854 |   2016-05-14 15:18:35 87.5 |  J20128 |    7036854  |
7033955 |   2016-05-14 15:20:45 83.4 |  9662   |    7033955  |
-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

the problem is why for example in record related to Serial N10088 the ID is "7031053", but MAX(ID) is "7031056"? or also for J20358?

each row must show last record of each item but in my output it is not true!

Comment: Your query will return the first ID it collects in the select `Serial` grouping, without any explicit ordering, the `Max(ID)` then returns the highest related ID in the `Serial` group. For comparison you can try: `select Min(ID), Calendar, Serial, Max(ID) from store group by Serial desc;` and possibly see a different result set. However, the ID that was being selected, may already be the `Min`, so there is no guarantee.

Comment: This is because of `group by Serial Desc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the row with the max value, then you need a join or some other mechanism.

Here is a simple way using a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
from store s
where s.id = (
   select max(s2.id) 
   from store s2 
   where s2.serial = s.serial
);
```

You query uses a (mis)feature of SQL Server that generates lots of confusion and is not particularly helpful:  you have columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by`.  What value do these get?

Well, in most databases the answer is simple:  the query generates an error as ANSI specifies.  MySQL pulls the values for the additional columns from indeterminate matching rows.  That is rarely what the writer of the query intends.

For performance, add an index on `store(serial, id)`.

Comment: when I run your simple way the CPU usage of my server  goes on 90% and it takes many time, is there any faster way?

Comment: @Ali - do you have an index on your `ID` and/or `Serial` columns? How large is your table?

Comment: @gmiley no I have not, table has ~ 30,000 rows

Comment: Adding indexes would speed up your queries then. Indexing should always be a part of your table design process. And knowledge of and proper use of those indexes should be a constant part of your query development processes.

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
SELECT MAX(id), tbl.*
FROM store tbl
GROUP BY Serial
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this also...

```
   SELECT ID,Calendar,Serial 
    FROM store s0
    where ID = (
       SELECT MAX(id) 
       FROM store s1 
       WHERE s1.serial = s0.serial
    );
```